# How disable a cookie key encryption in .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two apps (in same domain): the first created on Nodejs (express-session), ant the second on .Net Core.
Login provider is 1 app.

2 app - gets auth cookie and it has to start session. Session Cache is saved into Mongodb. 
Now 2 app is working good. But it always recreates cookie with encrypted key. In Mongodb session key saved not encrypted.

Where is problem? When user want to return into 1 app, he see login page. Because 1 app doesn't recognise the encrypted cookie key.

I think the best way - disable cookie key encryption in 2 app.

In my opinion (sorry, I'm beginner) with encryption works services.AddDataProtection().

```
public class AppDistributedSessionStore : ISessionStore
    {
        DistributedSessionStore innerStore;
        IStartSession startSession;

        public AppDistributedSessionStore(IDistributedCache cache,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IStartSession startSession)
        {
            innerStore = new DistributedSessionStore(cache, loggerFactory);
            this.startSession = startSession;
        }

        public ISession Create(string sessionKey, TimeSpan idleTimeout, TimeSpan ioTimeout, Func<bool> tryEstablishSession, bool isNewSessionKey)
        {
           // temp
            sessionKey = "Sfdfd_fddddufd45454dfdfdfre.WFCpMxXnpfdfdfdf7878dfdf7d8fd";
            ISession session = innerStore.Create(sessionKey, idleTimeout, ioTimeout,
            tryEstablishSession, isNewSessionKey);
            if (isNewSessionKey)
            {
                startSession.StartSession(session);
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IStartSession, InitSession>();
services.AddSingleton<ISessionStore, AppDistributedSessionStore>();

services.AddSession(o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = "app_session";
                o.Cookie.Path = "/";
                o.Cookie.IsEssential = true;               
            });
services.AddMongoDbCache(options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("NoSqlSettings")["ConnectionString"];

                options.DatabaseName = "appdb";
                options.CollectionName = "sessions";
                options.ExpiredScanInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

            });
```

2 app always put new cookie with encrypted key, like: CfDJ8LDy%2F5e6ELtApkua%2Bim6shYlqsO8GwVMf%2FKtOGSJzr6tCS8c%2BvIMG%2FopD%2BWrclJin07WBDSwRp66TPeDTCFI4Mu%2BWn2RsYY06JsvkQAqRIVXc0TZBIGOKGzqD1KouKLpv%2F9m63z2tUsA2plTddJj6j6oewul4z%2FnrL4GUFJ1XM%2BWW.

How stop to encrypt key? I want to see cookie with key: "Sfdfd_fddddufd45454dfdfdfre.WFCpMxXnpfdfdfdf7878dfdf7d8fd"

Comment: You should not send the cookie unencrypted, especially for an auth cookie. The solution here is to use a centralized identity provider like Identity Server. Your users auth against that, and then each individual app gets its authenticated state from that centralized provider. That way there's one auth cookie going to one destination and it can remain encrypted. Sharing cookies between apps is bad practice anyways.

Comment: @ChrisPratt but then I have to reformat 1 app. Because with auth works express-session. 2 app doesn't provide login. But why my cookie unencrypted? [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) encrypts.